# Reading a file using ftp in PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to read a csv file in a ftp server using php .
Below is my code:-
maps.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Circles</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
// This example creates circles on the map, representing
// populations in North America.

// First, create an object containing LatLng and population for each city.

    var citymap = [];
    var temp = [];
    <?php
        $data = array();
        $file = fopen("ftp://b7_15716007:xxxxxx@ftp.byethost7.com/htdocs/data.csv","r");
    while(!feof($file))
    {
        $data = fgetcsv($file);
    ?>
        temp.push("<?php echo $data[0]; ?>");
        temp.push("<?php echo $data[1]; ?>");
        temp.push("<?php echo $data[2]; ?>");
        temp.push("<?php echo $data[3]; ?>");
        citymap.push(temp);
        console.log(citymap);
        temp = [];
    <?php
    }
    fclose($file);
    ?>
var cityCircle;

function initialize() {
  // Create the map.
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
  // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
      var fillcolor=[];
      fillcolor[0]='#FF0000';fillcolor[1]='#FFFF00'; fillcolor[2]='#FF00FF';    fillcolor[3]='#00FF00';
      var loop=0;
     for (i = 0; i < citymap.length; i++) {  
    var populationOptions = {
      strokeColor: '#000000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,

      fillColor: fillcolor[loop],
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(citymap[i][1], citymap[i][2]),
      radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[i][3]) * 100000
    };

    // Add the circle for this city to the map.
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
   // cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions1);
    loop=loop+1;


  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code has to read the values in csv and represent them in a google map api .
But the code is not working . 
Can anyone please help me fix this .
The link for the csv is 
Even after passing the url with authentication I dont get the map being displayed .

Comment: What is not working, what are the errors? + I don't see you login on the FTP, so you can't open the CSV file.

Comment: because your ftp server requires authentication you need to use `ftp_get` http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php

Comment: updated the code with url having credentials but in vain

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just open password protected ftp resource like that.. You must use password for entering there.

Please, try to use some authentication functions like:

```
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}
```

Refer to: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php for more information.

Comment: I passed the url with authentication `ftp://b7_15716007:password@ftp.byethost7.com/htdocs/data.csv` but there is no change

Comment: @Newbie that's not going to work you need to use the functions in the answer above